# getting compile error : Sub or Function not defined in vba when trying to use Today() function

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting compile error : Sub or Function not defined in vba when trying to use Today() function at below line :

```
 Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("S" & row).Formula = WorksheetFunction.Days(Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("Q" & row), TODAY())
```

Comment: You probably mean NOW instead of TODAY. TODAY is not a built in function of VBA.

Comment: Thanks It solved my problem :)

Comment: There's a DATE function which returns the current date without the time portion.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Date` in place of `TODAY()` if you are comparing dates.